# Angular route resolve not waiting for promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm new to angular and I have a user route which I'm attempted to resolve the user object for before rendering the view. I've injected $q and deferred the promise, however, the view is still loading before the promise is returned.

Route:

```
.when('/user/:userId', {
    templateUrl: 'user/show.html',
    controller: 'UserController',
    resolve: {
        user: userCtrl.loadUser
    }
})
```

Controller

```
var userCtrl = app.controller('UserController', ['$scope',
    function($scope){
        $scope.user = user; // User is undefined

        // This fires before the user is resolved
        console.log("Fire from the controller");

    }]);

userCtrl.loadUser = ['Restangular', '$route', '$q',
    function(Restangular, $route, $q) {

        var defer = $q.defer();

        Restangular.one('users', $route.current.params.userId).get().then(function(data) {
            console.log("Fire from the promise");
            defer.resolve(data);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }];
```

Comment: It might be that the promise is not being resolved successfully. As per the docs, `$routeProvider` *should* wait until all promises are resolved before firing the `$routeChangeSuccess` event and switching the view.

Comment: Please put your answer in an... answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the Github issues, I found a similar problem and resolved it with the following:

```
userCtrl.loadUser = ['Restangular', '$route',
    function(Restangular, $route) {
        return Restangular.one('users', $route.current.params.userId).get();
    }];
```